# FB Like for photo doesn't work from the website

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I have an issue with FB Like from website. I've got two features to like, Page Posts and Page Photos. When I Like FB Post, it works, and like is counted on both Facebook Page Post and Website. But, when I try to like a photo, like counter on website increases to 1, and after a second drops to 0.

I have following configuration:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script>(function(d, s, id) {
          var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
          if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
          js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
          js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=111111111111111111111";
          fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Like button

```
'<fb:like href="' + urlToLike + '" send="false" layout="button_count" width="170" show_faces="false"></fb:like>';
```

URLs used for Post and Photo like:

```
photoUrlToLike = 'http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=111111111111&set=a.502954436404881.121467.265145956852398&type=1&permPage=1';
postUrlToLike = 'http://www.facebook.com/mydummypage/posts/1111111111111111';
```

So my question is since users can like posts from my website, why doesn't it work for photos as well. What am I missing here?

**Edit**

I've found facebook photo API :

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/

And this should be fairly simple to execute but I'm unable to do this for hours now. Quoting photo api:

```
likes


Create

You can like a photo by issuing a HTTP POST request to PHOTO_ID/likes connection with the publish_stream permission. No parameters necessary.
```

Assuming my page url is :

```
http://www.facebook.com/dummypage
```

And my Photo ID is `4234234234131`. Photo is on the wall of the dummy page.

How would my post URL look like? to which Url should I make POST request to?

Comment: _“How would my post URL look like? to which Url should I make POST request to?”_ – to `/PHOTO_ID/likes`, as the documentation already says.

Comment: so `http://facebook.com/PHOTO_ID/likes` ?

Answer (score 2):

I have recently get troubled on the same problem. After studying couple of hours, I got understand it's not the problem of my code or anything from my side. It's a small bug, even reported to facebook. Please check here: 
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/530674523672388?browse=external_tasks_search_results_51fd2ae4d0e0e1621568068

Another thing important to say, question says likes works for posts but not for photos. But I got things different from that. Same problem occurs for post containing attachment of external links content and any other contents!

I have managed posting likes using the system as said in question: You can like a photo by issuing a HTTP POST request to PHOTO_ID/likes connection with the publish_stream permission. No parameters necessary. Of course, you need a **valid access token** for the each user to execute this properly. You can use **[Facebook SDK for PHP](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/)** for getting access token by Authorization each user. It works for all standard object (post, photos, videos is tested properly), just need to pass a valid id of photo, post or video.

The code it simple and I have shown fake facebook like & liked (after like) button for this:

```
function like_std_object($object_id){
    try{
        $like=$facebook->api('/$object_id/likes','post'); //post a like using api
    }catch(FacebookApiException $e){
        return false;
    }
}
function unlike_std_object($object_id){
    try{
        $like=$facebook->api('/$object_id/likes','delete'); //post a un-like using api
    }catch(FacebookApiException $e){
        return false;
    }
}
```